# A property of closures and interiors

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck by this question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be 2 disjoint open sets in $(E,d)$.
Prove that $$int(\overline{A})\cap int(\overline{B}) = \emptyset$$.
I don't get how to use that they are open. Could someone give some help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Think about interior as the largest open set and closure as the smallest closed set. I don't know what the formulation you where given, but this formulation is how you solve this question

Comment: I'd say $int(\overline{A}) = int(A)$

Comment: @cronos2 What about $A = (0,1) \setminus \{ 1/2 \}$?

Comment: @amrsa Sure, I guess I outlined the connection issue a bit too soon. Apologies.

Comment: @amrsa then yours would not make any sense at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppse $x\in int(\bar{A})\cap int(\bar{B})$. Then there exists $d>0$ such that $B(x,d)\subset\bar{A}$ and $B(x,d)\subset\bar{B}$. You can show $B(x,d)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ because $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Similarly $B(x,d)\cap B\neq\emptyset$. So there exists $y\in B(x,d)\cap B$ such that $y$ is the limit point of $A$. Hence there is a neighborhood of $y$ containing points of $A$. Since $y\in B$, you can make this neighborhood small sufficiently such that it is contained in $B$. Then some points of $A$ are in $B$. Contradiction!

Comment: Why is y a limit point of A?

Comment: Because $B(x,d)$ is contained in $\bar{A}$ and each point of $\bar{A}$ is a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Using cl for closer, U = int cl A cap int cl B is open.
If U is not empty, there's some x in U.
Since x in U, x in cl A and there some y in U cap A.
Since y in cl B and U cap A is open, there be some. 
z in U cap A cap B, a contradicition.

Thus the proposition holds for all spaces.
Additionally, only one of A or B needs to be open.